# getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8") is not working in JSP page

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I'm making web site for my blog. and while I'm testing encoding to Other Language.

```
27   <%
28   String str = request.getParameter("stone");
29   out.println(new String(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8"));
30   %>
```

I don't know why this code make following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 29

Comment: Are you sure that `request.getParameter("stone")` doesn't return null?

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap my code in a try/catch construct. Thus,

```
String str;
try {
  str = request.getParameter("stone");
  out.println(new String(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8"));
} catch (Exception e) {
   out.print("<p>An unexpected exception occurred: " + e.getMessage() + "</p>");
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did that in try/catch. but it occured same error.